# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized

Tags: java, android

I have implemented Encryption / Decryption in Android application.

I have added an Encryption class which has been made a Singleton class.

Part of the code as follows:

```
public class Encryption {

        private SecretKeySpec mKey = null;
        private Cipher mCipher = null;
        private byte[] mKeyBytes = null;
        private AlgorithmParameterSpec mParamSpec = null;
        private static Encryption sInstance;

        public Encryption() {
            byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
            mParamSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            mKeyBytes = getMD5(MD5_KEY.getBytes();
            mKey = new SecretKeySpec(mKeyBytes, AES_TAG);
            try {
                mCipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION_STR);
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            }
        }

        public static synchronized Encryption getInstance() {
            if (sInstance == null) {
                sInstance = new Encryption();
            }
            return sInstance;
        }

        public String encryptString(String strPwd) {
            String strToEncripted = null;
            strToEncripted = strPwd;
            String result = null;
            byte[] input = null;
            byte[] cipherText = null;
            int ctLength = 0;
            try {
                input = strToEncripted.getBytes(UTF8_STR);
                mCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mKey, mParamSpec);
                cipherText = new byte[mCipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
                ctLength = mCipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
                ctLength += mCipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
                result = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, Base64.DEFAULT)
                        .replace(NEWLINE_CHAR, EMPTY_CHAR).trim();
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            }
            return result;
        }

        public String decryptstring(byte[] encripted) {
            String textDecrypt = "";
            byte[] encriptedByteDecode64 = Base64.decode(encripted, Base64.DEFAULT);
            byte[] plainText = new byte[mCipher.getOutputSize(encriptedByteDecode64.length)];
            int ptLength = 0;
            try {
                mCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mKey, mParamSpec);
                ptLength = mCipher.update(encriptedByteDecode64, 0, encriptedByteDecode64.length, plainText, 0);
                ptLength += mCipher.doFinal(plainText, ptLength);
                textDecrypt = (new String(plainText)).trim();
            } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            } catch (ShortBufferException e) {
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            }
            return textDecrypt;
        }


        private String getMD5(String strKey) {
            String key = strKey;
            String result = null;
            try {
                MessageDigest algorithm = MessageDigest.getInstance(MD5_TAG);
                algorithm.reset();
                algorithm.update(key.getBytes(UTF8_STR));
                byte messageDigest[] = algorithm.digest();
                StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder();
                for (int count = 0; count < messageDigest.length; count++) {
                    String hexaDecimal = Integer.toHexString(0xFF & messageDigest[count]);
                    while (hexaDecimal.length() < 2)
                        hexaDecimal = new StringBuilder(ZERO_STR).append(hexaDecimal).toString();
                    hexString.append(hexaDecimal);
                }
                result = hexString.toString();
            } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Using the singleton instance , encryption & decryption of string are implemented & they are working mostly.

Sometimes , though the cipher has been initialised , still its throwing an Exception: **`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized`**

The scenario is mostly when after some time-interval (30 mins), a decryption of string is performed.

Can it be due to the incorrect use of Singleton instance?

Instead of Singleton class , I have tried to encrypt string creating an instance of Encryption class using the new operator , but the problem is I need the same object for decryption , else the **`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cipher not initialized`** is thrown.

Any suggestions / hints are welcome.

Comment: you use it like `Encryption.getInstance().encryptString("123");`? From multiple threads or just from 1?

Comment: Have you managed to fix this problem? I am also suffering from the same issue - IllegalStateExceptions after several minutes of constant use. I even call init() before every use (due to a constantly changing IV). If you've managed to find the problem, please answer your own question with the solution. :)

Comment: was unable to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please do not use a singleton cipher, ever. Use a singleton *key* if you must, but cipher states should be *local* to the code where it is used. [previous comment was too snarky, my apologies]

Answer (score 10):

This problem is bound to occur in a multi threaded environment, as it happened to me. The issue is a clash between mCipher.init() and mCipher.doFinal() methods.

Following are the related methods in Cipher class:

```
public final void init(int opmode, Key key, AlgorithmParameterSpec params) throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
{
   init(opmode, key, params, JceSecurity.RANDOM);
}


public final void init(int opmode, Key key, AlgorithmParameterSpec params,
                       SecureRandom random)
        throws InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
{
    initialized = false;
    checkOpmode(opmode);

    if (spi != null) {
        checkCryptoPerm(spi, key, params);
        spi.engineInit(opmode, key, params, random);
    } else {
        chooseProvider(I_PARAMSPEC, opmode, key, params, null, random);
    }

    initialized = true;
    this.opmode = opmode;
}


public final int doFinal(byte[] output, int outputOffset)
        throws IllegalBlockSizeException, ShortBufferException,
           BadPaddingException {
    checkCipherState();

    // Input sanity check
    if ((output == null) || (outputOffset < 0)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Bad arguments");
    }

    chooseFirstProvider();
    return spi.engineDoFinal(null, 0, 0, output, outputOffset);
}


private void checkCipherState() {
    if (!(this instanceof NullCipher)) {
        if (!initialized) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cipher not initialized");
        }
        if ((opmode != Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE) &&
            (opmode != Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Cipher not initialized " +
                                            "for encryption/decryption");
        }
    }
}
```

See the behavior of the `initialized` variable in a multi threaded environment with two threads executing init() and doFinal(). The Exception returned is not related to the object not being actually initialized but the `initialized` variable being set to `false`.

I solved my issue by synchronizing my encryptString() and decryptString() methods. Hope you can get some insight by going through the Cipher code.

Comment: Voted this down as you can simply create separate ciphers per thread, using the same key. There is no need to share the (minimal) state of a cipher between threads this way.

Comment: Voted this down for the above reason as well.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure you call `Cipher.getInstance()` in your encrypt and decrypt methods.

```
cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION_STR);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, mKey, mParamSpec);
// encrypt code here
```

`getInstance()` method grabs a cipher instance for the current thread to avoid race conditions like the exception you just posted.

Answer (score 2):

In your `decryptstring` method, you call

```
byte[] plainText = new byte[mCipher.getOutputSize(encriptedByteDecode64.length)];
```

a few lines before you call

```
mCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, mKey, mParamSpec);
```

Since the cipher is not yet initialized when you call getOutputSize on it, you get the exception. Reordering these lines should fix it. (It did for me.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue (`Cipher not initialized`). I was using high-encryption and, for me, the solution was replacing the normal policy jars in `jre/lib/security` with the unlimited strength versions.

Comment: strange. the problem of multi-threading is actually solved by a synchronized(cipher_Object)-block

Answer (score 0):

if you use the method

```
public void initCipher(int encryptionMode) throws GeneralSecurityException {
         getCipher().init(encryptionMode, getKey());
     }
```

then you must get rid of this method immediately :D.
instead you can reinitialize the cipher in both the ConvertToEntity and ConvertToColumn methods. like:

```
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(Object attribute) {
        Cipher cipher = getCipher();
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKey());
        if (attribute == null)
            return null;
        byte[] bytes = SerializationUtils.serialize(attribute);
        assert bytes != null;
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(bytes));
    }
```

i just tried to help it worked for me and i hope for you to .
One more thing, am using @sneakyThrows instead of try and catch :D