# How to fix error exception java: error decryptAES Could not initialize cipher?

Tags: java, encryption, java-7

I have a exception, could not initialize cipher, and i can't fix it

This is code:

```
public static String decryptAES(String dataEncrypt, String key) throws Exception {
    synchronized(decryptLock) {
        String dataDecrypted = new String();
        try {
            Cipher aesCipher = getAesCipher();
            byte[] raw = hexToBytes(key);
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            aesCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, aesCipher.getParameters());

            byte[] decordedValue = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(dataEncrypt);

            byte[] byteDecryptedText = aesCipher.doFinal(decordedValue);
            dataDecrypted = new String(byteDecryptedText);
            return dataDecrypted;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error("error decryptAES " +ex.getMessage());
        }

        return dataDecrypted;
    }
```

and this is fuction getAesCipher():

```
private static synchronized Cipher getAesCipher() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException{
    if (_aesCipher == null) {
        _aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    }

    return _aesCipher;
}
```

Sometime view log, i see log error exception, but i can't fix it

This is log error:

```
(EncryptManager.java:decryptRSA(82)) - running decryptRSA ....
  (EncryptManager.java:decryptAES(624)) - error decryptAES Could not initialize cipher
```

Please help me !  Thanks

Comment: Specify the line of error or there must be actual stack trace, post that.

Comment: ok, thanks, i will edit

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10356137/java-lang-illegalstateexception-cipher-not-initialized

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more information, I would suggest you validate the hex key value provided to the method. I have not seen that exact error message, but `InvalidKeyException`s can be thrown when the key parameter is not valid for the cipher during initialization (the key is not a valid length for the algorithm, the key length is not supported by the JVM because the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy files are not installed, etc.).

How are you instantiating `_aesCipher` the first time? If it is only the code you posted that sets it to an instance of a `Cipher`, you probably don't need to pass the parameters when you call `cipher.init()`. However, you may want to look into using an IV and passing `IvParameterSpec` in to improve the security of this code. You should also specify the [mode of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) and padding scheme when instantiating the cipher as Java will default to `ECB`, which is highly insecure.